# punchDB / allDocs / .then return a value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pouchdb

I am new in js and punchDB and have problem in fetch data from pounchDB

this is usual in fetch data and process

```
 db.allDocs({include_docs: true}).then(function (result) {
    console.log( result.rows);
 }));
```

but I want to return "result.rows"

```
var result = db.allDocs({include_docs: true}).then(function (result) {
    return  result.rows;
}));
```

Yes I can have **allDocs** function output by skip **.then**

```
var result= db.allDocs({include_docs: true});
```

But it is a complex output

I also found this link 
http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html

that explain **return** when we have **.then** but it didn't work for **allDocs**

Comment: `var result` will not get `result.rows` but rather the promise to get `results.rows`. So, somewhere late you'd need to do `result.then(function(rows){ console.log(rows); })`

Comment: I got from your comment , I did  some thing  like put object in string(in language as C#) right? can you explain more  about your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you do something like the following:

```
var result = db.allDocs({include_docs: true}).then(function (result) {
    return result.rows;
});

console.log(result); // I expect to see rows here
```

This will NOT work, since `result` is not rows - it's the **promise** to get rows. The actual results would get there at a later time, asynchronously.

So, if you are doing this operation in some function or a service, and you do `return result`, the consumer of that function would still need to do `.then`. Here's what I mean:

```
function getRows(){
  var result = db.allDocs({include_docs: true}).then(function (result) {
        return result.rows;
  });

  return result;
}

getRows().then(function(rows){
   console.log(rows); // actual rows
})
```